# Differences between SliverList vs ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

What are the differences between `SliverList` and `ListView` in Flutter?

Comment: That question is totally legit.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. But didn't find any differences. That is why I asked about it.

Comment: @RafiqulHasan I am pretty sure @Adriaan will tell you that you havent`t looked thoroughly enough...:P

Comment: @Pascal This question was asked in 16 may, 2018. In that time flutter was in alpha stage. There was not much of documentation or article to find.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There's almost no difference.

`ListView` **is** a `SliverList`. Same with `GridView`, which is a `SliverGrid`.

They are doing exactly the same thing. The only difference between them is that `SliverList` is a sliver, not a widget. Which means it's used inside a `ScrollView`, usually `CustomScrollView`.

`ListView` is nothing else but a biding of `SliverList` to transform it into a `Widget` to make it usable alongside other widgets such as `Row`/`Container`.

---

Most of the time, use `ListView`.

But if you want advanced scroll behavior such as appbar animations with scroll ; you'll need to use a `CustomScrollView`. Which will force you to use `SliverList` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: with `SliverList` it's possible to use `SliverToBoxAdapter`, is there any equivalent for `ListView` which is not inside a sliver list ?

Answer (score 35):

According [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f),

> All of the scrollable views you use, like `ListView` and `GridView`,
>   are `actually implemented using Slivers`. You can kind of think of
>   Slivers as a lower-level interface, providing finer-grained control on
>   implementing scrollable area. Because slivers can lazily build each
>   item just as it scrolls into view, slivers are particularly useful for
>   efficiently scrolling through large numbers of children.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer as it defines the performance point .

Comment: just to note, lazy loading can also be achieved by using `ListView.builder()` too.

Comment: Also GridView.builder() has the same performance benefit of creating child elements as required.